# How to find special characters in a string and store in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

Example of a string

```
"/city=<A>/state=<B>/sub_div=<C>/type=pos/div=<D>/cli_name=Cstate<E>/<F>/<G>"
```

characters occurs like A, B, C and .... are variables and count is not fixed

How to identifies how many variables are there and stored in an array

Comment: do you have an example, the wanted output and what you have tried?

Comment: Are you looking for object or array? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

Use regex to find all your matches.
Using a while loop you can iterate through multiple matches and push them in an array. Try this.

```
var String = "/city=<A>/state=<B>/sub_div=<C>/type=pos/div=<D>/cli_name=Cstate<E>/<F>/<G>";
var myRegexp = /\<.\>/gm;
var matches = [];
var match = myRegexp.exec(String);

while (match != null) {  
  matches.push(match[0])
  match = myRegexp.exec(String);
}

console.log(matches)
```

Comment: @ShivajiWatekar anytime.. please mark it as a right answer if it really helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Please review below code that will help to resolve your issue. It may find any non word characters and create a non-word array.

```js
let str = "/city=<A>/state=<B>/sub_div=<C>/type=pos/div=<D>/cli_name=Cstate<E>/<F>/<G>";

let arrStr = str.split("");
var strRegExp = /\W/g;
let arrNonWord = [];

arrStr.forEach(function(str){
  var result = str.match(strRegExp);
  if(result)
   arrNonWord.push(result[0]);
});

console.log(arrNonWord);
```